# Unable to install LSF (v15.04) iOS Sample Application

Tags: ios, ipa, alljoyn

I would like to test AllSeen Alliance Lighting Service Framework (LSF) v15.04 Sample Application on iOS platform.

Platform details are: HW = iPad, SW = iOS:9.2, Build Version:13C75.

I have downloaded the IPA files from LSF WiKi page (https://wiki.allseenalliance.org/tsc/connected_lighting and https://build.allseenalliance.org/lighting/view/RB15_04/job/Lighting_Sample_App_iOS_RB15.04/1/) .

When I try to install the IPA files (through iTunes), the APP is getting copied to iPad but does not get installed. There is a mention of "Note: iOS Binary IPA is not signed, needs to be built from source" in the LSF Wiki page. Unfortunately I don't have a MAC machine to build IPA files from SDK/Source.

Can anyone help regarding this please ? I have queried to LSF mailing list and awaiting response for the same.

Thanks,

-Venkat.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it but you might try ifunbox. From what I have read it allows you to install unsigned ipa files on iOS devices without jailbreaking.